# Rails query portion of model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, model

How would i do a query like this.
i have

```
@model = Model.near([latitude, longitude], 6.8)
```

Now i want to filter another model, which is associated with the one above.
 (help me with getting the right way to do this)

```
model2 = Model2.where("model_id == :one_of_the_models_filtered_above", {:one_of_the_models_filtered_above => only_from_the_models_filtered_above})
```

the model.rb would be like this

```
has_many :model2s
```

the model2.rb

```
belongs_to :model
```

Im on rails 3

Right now it is like this (after @model = Model.near([latitude, longitude], 6.8)

```
model2s =[]
models.each do |model|
   model.model2s.each do |model2|
      model2.push(model2)
   end
end
```

I want to accomplish the same thing,  but with an active record query instead

I partially found an answer to my question. It still incorporates my old method which i am unhappy about.

```
models.each do |model|
   models-model2s = Model2.where("model_id => :modid",{:modid => model.id})
   model2 += model
end
```

But this is a kind of a dumb approach, fooling around with tadman's approach showed me that model.model2s is a command i can execute (which i forgot), so

```
models.each do |model|
   model2s += model.model2s
end
```

This isn't completely what i was looking for, but im using it until i see something better. (Im still thinking of tadman's reverse approach)

i think i found something, why does this fail

```
Model2.where("model.distance_from([:latitude,:longitude]) < :dist", {:latitude => latitude, :longitude => longitude, :dist => 6.8})
```

this query throws this error

```
SQLite3::SQLException: near "(": syntax error: SELECT "tags".* FROM "tags"  WHERE (model.distance_from([43.45101666666667,-80.49773333333333]) < 6.8)
```

, why

Comment: Sorry - what exactly should the second line of code do?  I'm having trouble understanding.

Comment: @Nick edited question above, see again

Answer (score 1):

You might have some luck with just retrieving the second type of model indirectly:

```
@models = Model.near([ latitude, longitude ], 6.8).includes(:model2s)
```

That will pre-load all the "model2s".

Or you can try flipping it around and retrieving the Model2s directly, but you'd have to be able to express the `near` condition some other way:

```
@model2s = Model2.includes(:model).where('models.x' => ...)
```